# how to remove security settings from a connection string in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

hi i am trying to add data to the database that was created by some one but when am trying to insert or delete or update the exception is raising and entire project is not working properly and the error i am facing is

*"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"*

so now what should i do to resolve this error and my connection string is written as

```
Dim CON As New SqlConnection("Integrated Security=SSPI;
    Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DIGITALGAMES;
                                       Data Source=TEJUS-PC\SQLEXPRESS")
```

is there any problem with my connection string ??

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the local sqlexpress database or a remote one?

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes when database path is wrong i.e. system is enabe to locate the database

plz make apropriate modifications in

Data Source=TEJUS-PC\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: TEJUS-PC\SQLEXPRESS that is my system server path and i am using windows authentication as default how can u modify in the sonnection srting to get this problem solved

Comment: and yes DIGITALGAMES is my database name

Comment: "Data Source=TEJUS-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DIGITALGAMES;Integrated Security=SSPI;"..........try this one...sure it will help you

Comment: again showing same error in CON.Open()
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: instead of Integrated Security=SSPI; try out ...Integrated Security=true;...and tell me..

Comment: is there any loginid or password u r keeping to log into ur server?

Comment: no.. by default it  is windows authentication and was developed in another system i copied the entire database to my computer

Comment: is it sqlserver 2008 express or r2???? ...and have u copied log file also?have u pasted it in apropriate folder?

Comment: no the problem is not been solved.. and it is sql server 2005, yes i had copied log file also and both mdf and log file are in same folder.....

Comment: have you followed the procedure of attachment of database?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim CON As New SqlConnection("Integrated Security=SSPI;
    Initial Catalog=DIGITALGAMES;Data Source=TEJUS-PC\SQLEXPRESS; User ID=yourusername; Password=yourpassword")
```

and
try this [link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005)
, with useful information about connection string

Answer (score 0):

I think the server you are trying to access is either not in the network or you dont have windows authentication to that server.

Comment: what are the changes that i can perform on the connection string or ay other way to solve this problem.. can u plzz give in a detailed list of points so that i will follow

Comment: see for this you need to first check loging into the server there first by windows authentication if not accessible then try using userid & password.If both does not work then you have to contact your DBA there

Comment: i succeeded in loging into the server by windows authentication and attached my database DIGITALGAMES.mdf to the server and tested connection it was successfull and again am facing the same problem in inserting the values to the database agai it showing the same error/ exception